# Not able to read the google sheets in R using gs_ls function?

Tags: r, google-sheets, error-handling, google-sheets-api

Till today this program was running very smoothly but, when I try to access the google sheet after the authentication still showing the err in R (Error in function_list[k] : Not Found (HTTP 404).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've loaded googlesheets4 in your library, but are using googlesheets (not 4) commands- gs_auth(). You should use gs4_auth() for googlesheets4.

Yes, my googlesheets (gs_auth()) stopped working recently, too. When using gs_auth(), I am getting that the app is blocked by google.